# how to access to my local directory files and return response.json at adonis 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

Hello im using adonis 5 for to make a API REST, in this moment im reading the oficial guide and i not found a way for to access and return files in my response.json (In AdonisJs 4.1 i can to make this using "Drive"), i only found how to save files at local Storage drive but not how to acces to my files at drive

¿There is a way of how to solved my problem using the same dependences of adonis 5 or i need to install another dependence?

Thanks for your's answers.

im reading: https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/http/file-uploads and no found a solved or similar topics at guide

Answer (score 0):

`Drive` functionality has not been migrated to v5. See the roadmap for v5 [here](https://trello.com/b/3klaHbfP/adonisjs-roadmap-2020).

What you can do for now is to store files under a public directory, e.g. `public/uploads/` and then return back the **file URL** to clients.

**Bonus point:**
You can define a custom public dir. in your .adonisrc.json file:

```
"directories": {
  "public": "./public/uploads"
}
```